# Undo-Redo functionality using Command-Pattern in Qt for FitInView feature

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, command-pattern

I have `QGraphicsView` which contains some `QGraphicsItem`. This view has some feature like `zoom-in`, `zoom-out`, `fitIn`, `Undo-Redo`.
My `fitIn` feature is not working in `Undo-Redo` functionality.
( To implement `Undo-Redo` I have used `Command-Pattern` in Qt. )

myCommand.h

```
class myCommand: public QUndoCommand
{
public:
    myCommand();
    myCommand(QTransform t, int hr, int vr, QGraphicsView* v);
    void undo();
    void redo();
    QTransform t;
    int hScrollBar;
    int  vScrollBar;
    QGraphicsView* mView;
};
```

myCommand.cpp

```
myCommand::myCommand(QTransform t, int hr, int vr, QGraphicsView *v)
{
    this->t = t;
    this->hScrollBar= hr;
    this->vScrollBar= vr;
    this->mView = v;
}

void myCommand::undo()
{
    mView->setTransform(t);
    mView->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(hScrollBar);
    mView->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(vScrollBar);
}

void myCommand::redo()
{
   myView mv;
   mv.FitInView();
}
```

myView.cpp

```
 void myView::FitIn()
    {
        FitInView();
        QTransform t = view->transform();
        int hrValue = view->horizontalScrollBar()->value();
        int vrValue = view->verticalScrollBar()->value();
        myCommand* Command1 = new myCommand(t,hrValue,vrValue,view);
        undoStack->push(Command1);   
    }

void myView::DrawDesign()
{
   // Logic for inserting all the Rectangles and polylines.
   QTimer::singleShot(100, this, [&]() {
        FitInView();
    });
}

void myView::FitInView()
{
    QRectF bounds = scene->sceneRect();
    QRectF rect  {0,0,200,200};
    if (bounds.width() < 200)
    {
        rect .setWidth(bounds.width());
        bounds.setWidth(200);
    }
    if (bounds.height() < 200)
    {
        rect.setWidth(bounds.height());
        bounds.setHeight(200);
    }
    view->fitInView(bounds, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    view->updateGeometry();
}
```

myView.h

```
public:
      QUndoStack* undoStack;
```

`FitInView` fits my design perfectly but it does not work in `Undo-Redo` feature.
I think I am making a mistake in `myCommand::undo()` and `myCommand::redo()` function.

Comment: Note for future readers: this is a follow up question of [How to get current visible portion of QGraphicsView in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71636589/how-to-get-current-visible-portion-of-qgraphicsview-in-qt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the many question you posted on the [Qt's Undo Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundo.html), it seems to me you are missing an essential part of the Command pattern:

> The Command pattern is based on the idea that **all editing** in an
> application is done **by creating instances of command objects**. Command
> objects apply changes to the document and are stored on a command
> stack. Furthermore, each command knows how to undo its changes to bring the document back to its previous state. [[1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundo.html)]

So all changes, should be implemented inside the [`QUndoCommand`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html#details) (follow the link to discover a basic usage example), i.e. inside [`QUndoCommand::redo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html#redo). Once the command is pushed on the `QUndoStack`, using [`QUndoStack::push`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundostack.html#push), the change (i.e. `QCommand::redo`) is automatically performed:

> Pushes `cmd` on the stack or merges it with the most recently executed command. In either case, **executes `cmd` by calling its redo() function.** [[4](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundostack.html#push)]

#### Steps to create a new `QUndoCommand`

1. Implement the desired changes inside `QUndoCommand::redo` (and not somewhere else).
2. Write the inverse of this command inside `QUndoCommand::undo`. If needed, capture the initial state inside the `QUndoCommand` constructor, to easily revert `QUndoCommand::redo`.

#### Applied to your example

So, the only action that `myView::FitIn` should perform, is pushing the command on the undo stack:

```
void myView::FitIn()
{
    undoStack->push(new fitCommand(view));   
}
```

Implement your changes inside the redo command:

```
void fitCommand::redo()
{
    mView->FitInView(); // Can be implemented using QGraphicsView::fitInView
}
```

As the inverse operation of fitting is not uniquely defined, we store the initial state inside the `QUndoCommand` constructor (to be able to restore the initial state inside `QUndoCommand::undo`):

```
fitCommand::fitCommand(myView *view)
{
    this->t = view->transform();
    this->hScrollBar= view->horizontalScrollBar()->value();
    this->vScrollBar= view->verticalScrollBar()->value();
    this->mView = view;
}
```

Now we can implement the `undo` command to revert the `redo` command:

```
void fitCommand::undo()
{
    mView->setTransform(t);
    mView->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(hScrollBar);
    mView->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(vScrollBar);
}
```

#### Usefull reading material:

- [Overview of Qt's Undo Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundo.html)
- [Detailed description of `QUndoCommand`, including basic code example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html#details)

Comment: Thank you for your EXCELLENT reply.  The best reply I ever got.

Comment: I have some problem in `redo()`. It is not working.  If I dont use `fitIn` functionality then `undo-redo` works perfectly. But If I use `fitIn` then `redo` does not work.  Means if I do like `zoom-in (1)`, `zoom-in (2)`,`zoom-in (3)`, `fitIn(4)` and then if I press 2 times `Undo` then I reach at (2) and then If I press `redo` then I reach at (3) but If I press it again then I do not reach at (4).

Comment: I have added little bit code of `FitInView()` to understand it properly.  And I have changed `undo()`and `redo()` as per your suggestion.

Comment: In `myCommand::redo`, you are now creating a new temporary view. This temporary view is correctly fitted into view (but never shown on screen). You should alter your original view, i.e. `this->mView`. Either you move to code of `myView::FitInView` to `fitCommand::redo` or you hold a pointer to myView (instead of QGraphicsView) in `fitCommand`.

Comment: You are still calling `FitInView();` directly from `myView::FitIn`. This should only be called from inside `fitCommand::redo` as explained in this post. However, note that it isn't a good idea to change the question (drastically) after an answered to keep the question and answer useful for other users who encounter the same issue in the future. Adding extra information information is off course no problem, but try to keep the original question intact.

Comment: Perfectly worked ! Now my `fitIn()` is working perfectly. Thank you for your help. And very nice reply ! :)

Comment: Can you look into this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72122800/can-we-use-multiple-stack-in-qts-undo-framework-command-pattern     I got reply and my issue was solved. But I want you to look into `zoom-in/out` code.  The problem is :  `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` feature working properly but when I use `Undo` that time problem occurs. Lets say for each `zoom-in` I have incresed ratio by 2x then for 3 time zoom in size gets increses by 6x but while Undoing it, it comes to 3x. Means for each `Undo` it reduces only for 1x.  Am I wrong in `scaleFactor`  ?

Comment: For normal `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` it works perfectly. ( means `zoom-out` brings my design to original scale. )  But lets say `zoom-in (2x)`,`zoom-in (2x)`,`zoom-in (2x)` then if I used `Undo(1x)`, `Undo(1x)` , `Undo(1x)` . `Undo` does not bring my design to original scale.

Comment: Problem is the same as in this question: all changes should be made inside the `QUndoCommand::redo` (and `QUndoCommand::undo`), as `redo` is automatically called when pushed to the stack. So the scale factor is initially applied twice: once inside `myView::ZoomIn` and once inside `myCommand::redo`.

Comment: It may be useful to debug your code (place a breakpoint inside `ZoomIn` and `redo`), so you will see that the zoom factor is indeed applied twice.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you once again for your explanation.